# Terraform: Route53 A and AAAA in same record?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

**Situation:**
I have different **A and AAAA records** that go to the same subdomain-name.

Like

- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (ipv4)

and

- xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx (ipv6)

that go to the **same subdomain** like xxxx.yyyyy.com

Now I use the following snippet in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "blablubb" { 
  zone_id = ""
  name    = "blablubb.something.com."
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "3600"
  records = [
    "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
  ]
}
```

I cannot find any hint in the docs by now:
[Terraform AWS Route53](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html)

**Assuption:**
I assume that I have to put both A and AAAA in the snippet.

**Question:**
How should that look if I am right?

Comment: These are 2 separate records that happen to be resolvable by the same name (but you'd want to resolve the different types or use `any`). So you need to create 2 separate records to do this with the same name and the same zone.

Comment: Error: Duplicate resource "aws_route53_record" configuration

  on main.tf line 270:
 270: resource "aws_route53_record" "www" { 

A aws_route53_record resource named "www" was already declared at
main.tf:259,1-36. Resource names must be unique per type in each module.


So do I have to declare two modules?

Comment: No, just name the resource differently. So `resource "aws_route53_record" "www_a"` and `resource "aws_route53_record" "www_aaaa"`